maui android fails get web api
I have created in vs2022 a web api running into aq IIS sevrer and connected to a sqlserver database. I have created a MAUI windows app to consume this api and all is OK. I have created a new MAUI app for Android and IOS. In both case, the
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://webapicd:7134/api/Cds/11/");
fails with [DOTNET] Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
the web api code is :
using cd.Data;
using cd.ModelsCd;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace cd.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class CdsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly cdContext _context;

        public CdsController(cdContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/Cds
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Cd>>> GetCd()
        {
            return await _context.Cd.ToListAsync();
        }

        // GET: api/Cds/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Cd>> GetCd(int id)
        {
            var cd = await _context.Cd.FindAsync(id);

            if (cd == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return cd;
        }
}

**The code I used to get info is : **
static async Task LectureAsync2()
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://WebApiCd:7134/");

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    try
    {
        // get 1 CD
        Console.WriteLine("GET 1 Cd");
        fich Cds1 = null;
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://webapicd:7134/api/Cds/11");

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Cds1 = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<fich>();
        }

        Console.WriteLine(Cds1.CdNom);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}

**
I have added to android manifest**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
                 android:debuggable="true" 
                 android:allowBackup="true" 
                 android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" 
                 android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicon_round" 
                 android:supportsRtl="true" 
                 ></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>

**and to network_security_config.xml file **
<network-security-config>
  <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">10.1.0.10</domain>
  </domain-config>
</network-security-config>

Nota : 10.1.0.10 is the ip adress of the IIS server, the sqlserver ip adress is 10.1.0.11

You can recheck if you have initialized variable client. For example: HttpClient client = new HttpClient();.

Yes it is initialized. The code is :

static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

Could you please post the full log of this problem?

[DOTNET] GET 1 Cd
Thread started: .NET Timer #5
Thread started:  #6
Thread started: .NET TP Gate #7
Thread started:  #8
[DOTNET] Connection failure
[CompatibilityChangeReporter] Compat change id reported: 237531167; UID 10190; state: DISABLED
[OpenGLRenderer] Unknown dataspace 0
[Choreographer] Skipped 547 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

As the code works fine for windows maui app, I think there is specific action to do on android side. For info, in the DNS the web api is referenced and respond to ping. More information : Into the samsung s21 browser, if I enter http://webapicd:7134/api/Cds/11,  I receive the good row.

your Console.Writeline is throwing the exception because Cds1 is null.  Most likely it is unable to connect and is timing out.  Have you verified connectivity to the server using the Android browser?  Is your server setup to handle remote requests?

Yes,  Into the samsung s21 browser, if I enter webapicd:7134/api/Cds/11, I receive the good row. I only have dotnet error when using the maui program. This means that the conection to the sqlserver is OK, DNS also because the web api web server (webapicd) responds to ping

Have you tested on other devices?

Yes I have tried with a s24, same result. As the web api is working fine with windows maui app, I think that the problem is in the access of the network by Android. I have created the network_security_config.xml file and modified the manifest.xml. I looking in blogs but most of them don't indicate info on networking with android.

I have also modified the network security config file to work with 10.0.2.2 address : always the same result. As I think the problem is in the networking process of android, I have also tried to access the web api with one imac and mac console app. It's working fine.

Have you tried to access the link on the browser of your android device?

Yes i have done this. See previous answers

You can try debugging with the developer of the API to see what went wrong.
